# Dequoting a vim argument

Tags: vim

I want to remove the quotes around a vim argument `[<f-args>][0]`.

The problem I'm having is that when I define a new command and call it with an argument say: `MyCommand Blah`, this gets called like `:MyCommand "Blah"`. The thing is, I want the argument `Blah` to be dequoted because I have an enviroment variable that I want to prefix the argument with `$` so that the full command actually reads something like `:MyCommand $Blah`.

How do I dequote the argument?

Comment: Use `<args>` instead of `<f-args>`.

Comment: @romainl what if I want to have more than 1 args. How would I get the first or second argument? with `<f-args>` I can can do `[<f-args>][0]` and `[<f-args>][1]`

Comment: `split(<args>, " ")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<f-args>` is for passing custom command arguments to a Vimscript *function*; there, you need quoting to pass those arguments as strings.

If you want to pass arguments to another (built-in or custom) command, just use `<args>`, which passes the arguments as-is.

If you need to pick apart the arguments, pass some to command X and others to command Y, this again is best done not inline in the `:command` definition, but in a function, so the `<f-args>` approach would work just fine.

#### Example

```
command! -nargs=* Test call TestFunc(<f-args>)

function! TestFunc( ... )
    echomsg 'argument 1 is' a:1
    echomsg 'arguments 2, 3 are' join(a:000[1:2])
endfunction
```